# Running sample PhoneGap apllication 'cordova-bada-wac' on Bada IDE emulator

Tags: cordova, ide, emulation, bada

I've download sample project from https://github.com/apache/cordova-bada-wac and try to run application using PhoneGap on Bada IDE.
I've properly configured Bada IDE v.2.0.5 (WVGA) and API version 2.0. When import this project as "Bada Flash / C++ project" and run in "bada emulator web application" i've this error:

Info, Installation completed.
0027.312,INFO,P32,T00,A121,OspMain (26) > Application started.
0034.505,INFO,P32,T00,A126,Osp::Web::Controls::_*WebService::AddMessageToConsole (3938) > Device Cellular network status: 0 at line 4195 loaded from file osp://www.texp59v0qj.com/Res/js/cordova.js
0034.522,INFO,P32,T00,A126,Osp::Web::Controls::*_WebService::AddMessageToConsole (3938) > Error NOT_AVAILABLE_ERR at line 4191 loaded from file osp://www.texp59v0qj.com/Res/js/cordova.js

When "texp59v0qj" is application ID from manifest.xml. I've try too with own manifest.xml generated from bada developer site.

Sample "bada web application project" generated from IDE run propertly. So maybe is some erro in this sample project "cordova-bada-wac" ?

Is sameone try and run this application ?

```
This is full log on running this application:


6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.019,9|10|bada Broker 2.0.3.20111121

Connected to the bada IDE!

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.031,AT+CGMM

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.031,Wave-E

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.031,OK

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.032,AT+LCDINFO=MAIN

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.033,+LCDINFO: 480,800

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.033,OK

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.034,AT+LCDINFO

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.035,ERROR

8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.036,AT+GETDPIMG=0

3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:17.049,00002|78:62:111|PHONESTATUS:00>  Launch Is Ready


8,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:20.567,OK

[SM]:Command message:[[1600:1601]GetAppInstallCondition texp59v0qj 1425169]

3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:20.570,00003|10:52:90|PHONESTATUS:12> errType=0, install is possible


[SM]:Command message:[[1600:1601]TerminateProcessEx texp59v0qj 0]

[SM]:Command message:[[1600:1601]UseDrmWrite webapp]

Creating an application folder on target device...

Creating application sub-folders on target device...

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.095,1|1|30|1425169

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.096,1|2|0|0|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Bin\WebAppLoader.exe|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Bin/WebAppLoader.exe

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Bin\WebAppLoader.exe
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Bin/WebAppLoader.exe  ( 0.000 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.099,1|2|1|1810|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Info\application.xml|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Info/application.xml

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Info\application.xml
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Info/application.xml  ( 0.002 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.114,1|2|2|1795|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Info\manifest.xml|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Info/manifest.xml

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Info\manifest.xml
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Info/manifest.xml  ( 0.002 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.126,1|2|3|222148|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\codova_bada_wac_splash_type4.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/codova_bada_wac_splash_type4.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\codova_bada_wac_splash_type4.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/codova_bada_wac_splash_type4.png  ( 0.151 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.283,1|2|4|107580|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\codova_bada_wac_splash_type5.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/codova_bada_wac_splash_type5.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\codova_bada_wac_splash_type5.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/codova_bada_wac_splash_type5.png  ( 0.072 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.361,1|2|5|4111|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_icon_type5.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_icon_type5.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_icon_type5.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_icon_type5.png  ( 0.003 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.367,1|2|6|5758|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_wac_icon_type3.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_wac_icon_type3.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_wac_icon_type3.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_wac_icon_type3.png  ( 0.004 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.376,1|2|7|7287|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_wac_icon_type4.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_wac_icon_type4.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_wac_icon_type4.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_wac_icon_type4.png  ( 0.005 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.385,1|2|8|90555|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_wac_splash_type3.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_wac_splash_type3.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\cordova_bada_wac_splash_type3.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/cordova_bada_wac_splash_type3.png  ( 0.061 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.452,1|2|9|3834|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\css\index.css|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/css/index.css

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\css\index.css
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/css/index.css  ( 0.003 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.465,1|2|10|21814|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\img\logo.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/img/logo.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\img\logo.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/img/logo.png  ( 0.015 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.484,1|2|11|1868|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\index.html|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/index.html

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\index.html
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/index.html  ( 0.002 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.495,1|2|12|208656|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\js\cordova.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/js/cordova.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\js\cordova.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/js/cordova.js  ( 0.196 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.734,1|2|13|1963|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\js\index.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/js/index.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\js\index.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/js/index.js  ( 0.002 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.745,1|2|14|4111|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\icon\bada-wac\icon-48-type5.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-48-type5.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\icon\bada-wac\icon-48-type5.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-48-type5.png  ( 0.006 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.755,1|2|15|5758|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\icon\bada-wac\icon-50-type3.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-50-type3.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\icon\bada-wac\icon-50-type3.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-50-type3.png  ( 0.004 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.762,1|2|16|7287|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\icon\bada-wac\icon-80-type4.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-80-type4.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\icon\bada-wac\icon-80-type4.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-80-type4.png  ( 0.005 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.771,1|2|17|90555|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\screen\bada-wac\screen-type3.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type3.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\screen\bada-wac\screen-type3.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type3.png  ( 0.061 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.838,1|2|18|222148|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\screen\bada-wac\screen-type4.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type4.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\screen\bada-wac\screen-type4.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type4.png  ( 0.153 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:22.997,1|2|19|107580|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\screen\bada-wac\screen-type5.png|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type5.png

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\res\screen\bada-wac\screen-type5.png
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type5.png  ( 0.072 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.075,1|2|20|6915|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\sample\index.html|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/sample/index.html

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\sample\index.html
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/sample/index.html  ( 0.005 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.091,1|2|21|184903|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\sample\js\cordova.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/sample/js/cordova.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\sample\js\cordova.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/sample/js/cordova.js  ( 0.184 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.310,1|2|22|11708|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\sample\js\sample.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/sample/js/sample.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\sample\js\sample.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/sample/js/sample.js  ( 0.008 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.331,1|2|23|1297|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\helper.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/helper.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\helper.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/helper.js  ( 0.001 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.340,1|2|24|2671|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\index.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/index.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\index.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/index.js  ( 0.002 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.351,1|2|25|19681|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\jasmine-html.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine-html.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\jasmine-html.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine-html.js  ( 0.014 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.383,1|2|26|6525|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\jasmine.css|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine.css

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\jasmine.css
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine.css  ( 0.005 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.402,1|2|27|71170|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\jasmine.js|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine.js

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\jasmine.js
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine.js  ( 0.048 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.497,1|2|28|1081|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\MIT.LICENSE|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/MIT.LICENSE

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec\lib\jasmine-1.2.0\MIT.LICENSE
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/MIT.LICENSE  ( 0.001 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.501,1|2|29|2600|s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec.html|/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec.html

Transferred: s:\mobile\bada\2.0.5\Temp\texp59v0qj\Res\spec.html
  ->  /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Res/spec.html  ( 0.002 sec)

6,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:23.512,1|5

Transfer completed.

[SM]:Command message:[[1600:1601]EnableDiagWrite]

[SM]:Command message:[[1600:1601]AppPkgInstall /Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj]

[SM]:Command message:[[0:2]MID_PROCESSMGR,0xFF]

[SM]:Command message:[[0:2]MID_DIAGMGR,0xFF]

[SM]:Command message:[[0:2]MID_DIAGMGR,0xFF]

3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:24.102,00004|10:52:90|PHONESTATUS:04> app installed, errType=0


Installation completed.

2,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:24.102,Info, Installation completed.

[SM]:Command message:[[1400:1400]/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Bin/WebAppLoader.exe,/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Bin]

3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:24.173,00005|78:62:111|PROCESSMGR:00> 32,/Osp/Applications/texp59v0qj/Bin/WebAppLoader.exe


2,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:24.842,0027.312,INFO,P32,T00,A121,OspMain (26) > Application started.

3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:24.964,[10800:10800]0027:432,texp59v0qj,/Home/texp59v0qj


3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:24.987,[11100:11100]0027:458,texp59v0qj,cordova-bada-wac


3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:25.888,[11000:11000]0028:358,texp59v0qj,,536870915


3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:27.556,[10400:10400]0030:026,texp59v0qj,


3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:31.155,[10400:10400]0033:624,texp59v0qj,


2,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:32.034,0034.505,INFO,P32,T00,A126,Osp::Web::Controls::__WebService::AddMessageToConsole (3938) > Device Cellular network status: 0 at line 4195 loaded from file osp://www.texp59v0qj.com/Res/js/cordova.js

2,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:09:32.052,0034.522,INFO,P32,T00,A126,Osp::Web::Controls::__WebService::AddMessageToConsole (3938) > Error NOT_AVAILABLE_ERR at line 4191 loaded from file osp://www.texp59v0qj.com/Res/js/cordova.js

3,0,0,1,2012-12-20,14:11:03.266,00006|117:-1:-1|PROCESSMGR:04> 32,0
```

Answer (score -1):

Error message directs to line 4191 where wifi status is checked and if value is not connected, then error is shown. Have you tried running this app by turning on wifi ? Because by looking at the [source code of file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-bada-wac/blob/master/Res/js/cordova.js) giving error, it looks like it is not able to interpret whether wifi is connected or not. May be you should try running this app on bada phone with wifi in connected and working state.